# Meaning of "completion to panel". Is this good usage of the word "completion"?

Tags: meaning, translation

From an autoclave manual (Tuttnauer Electronic Tabletop Autoclaves Models 1730, 2340, 2540, 3140, 3850, 3870 E, EK, EA & EKA)

> **15** Completion to panel

What is the meaning of "completion" here? Is this good usage of English? I'm trying to understand how to translate this.

If it's not natural English, what would be the natural English phrase to use in its place?

> [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would probably sound more natural as *completion **of** panel*. Although, even with the better preposition, that still sounds like truncated English—the kind of truncation commonly used in news headlines where certain words are omitted.

But as a simple noun, one that best matches all of the other entries in the diagram, I would think of it as a **panel completion strip**.

Answer (score 0):

From the diagram, it looks like it refers to the little strip that *completes* the panel.

This uses the term *completion* (normally the act or state of finishing something - [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/completion)) as a metonym for the thing that, when in place, achieves the completion.